# PC starts immediately after shutting down

Tags: networking, lan, shutdown, wake-on-lan

recently my PC starts up again immediately after I shut it down or put it to sleep. This has been happening since I set up Wake on LAN. I'm convinced it's the LAN connection but I don't know how to check or solve the problem.

The command `powercfg -lastwake` does not give me any useful information.

I tried to update my LAN controller using the device manager - nothing works.
I have selected the setting under Properties that only the Magic Packet can start the computer, but this does not solve the problem. Then I disabled the LAN adapter's ability to start the PC at all (Device Manager -> Properties -> Power Management) but that didn't help either.

When I unplug the LAN cable and shut down the PC it stays off. But only like this.

I still have the assumption that it is activated via the standard port for WOL over the internet by some packets coming through that are not meant for my PC.
I turned off the WOL option in BIOS. This works and the PC seems to stay off so it must have something to do with wake on lan.
I would really appreciate helpful answers without having to reboot the PC.

Side infos:

- Windows 11
- LAN Adapter: Realtek RTL8111H Gigabit LAN
- Mainboard: Asus Prime B450-Plus AM4 ATX

Comment: Did you enable Wake-on-LAN in the BIOS? Have you made sure it is no longer enabled there? (Sorry, that'll need a reboot to check.) Also, WOL packets should only travel over the LAN, and not through a router.

Comment: Do you want to disable WOL completely or do you want to wake up your PC when it receives the magic packet?

Comment: @zomega I don't want to disable WOL. I want to prevent my PC from starting by itself after shuting it down. But if this problem hangs together with WOL I'm ready too turn off WOL for testcases

Comment: @AndrewMorton I will try to disable WOL in the bios and see what happpens.

Comment: @AndrewMorton After turning off WOL in BIOS the PC stays off. So the problem is Wake on LAN

Comment: @KindOfTrue Are you sure that the device you are going to be sending the WOL packet from (remember it has to be on the same LAN) is not sending out WOL packets all the time?

Comment: @KindOfTrue Please update your BIOS firmware and add a photo of the BIOS WOL settings. There are WOL types which do not require a magic packet. For example WOL "link change". But for me it looks like a bug.